# duplicate URLs in my page, best solution?

Tags: search, browser, seo, friendly-url

I have a website that write URLs like this:

mypage.com/post/3453/post-title-name-person

In fact, what is important is the post and ID part (3453). The title I just add for SEO.

I changed some title names recently, but people can still using the old URL to access, because I just get the ID to open the page, so:

mypage.com/post/3453/post-title-name-person

mypage.com/post/3453/name-person
...

Will open the same page.

Is it wrong? Google webmaster tools tells me that I have 8765 duplications pages. So, to try to solve this I am redirecting old title to post/id/current-title but it seems that Google doesn't understand this redirecting and still give me duplications.

Should i redirect to not found if title doesn't match with the actual data base? (But this can be a problem because links that people shared won't open) Or what?

Comment: How do you redirect?

Comment: @unor using PHP - `header location` - header("Location: $newurl");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Google has not processed your redirections yet. It may take several weeks and sometimes several months to process all pages, especially if they are not revisited often. Make sure your redirects are 301 and not 302 (temporary).

That being said, there is a better method than redirections for duplicate pages: the [canonical tag](https://moz.com/learn/seo/canonicalization). If you can, implement it. There is less risk to mix up redirections.

Answer (score 1):

Google can pick your new URL's only after the implementation of [301 redirection through .htaccess file](http://findnerd.com/list/view/Redirection-through--htaccess-file/11294/). You should always need to remember that 301 re-direct should be proper and one to one to the new url. After this implementation you need to fetch those new URL via Google Search console so that Google index those URL's fast.